# Power of hatha yoga?

Tags: hatha-yoga

Considering that gym nowadays provide an excellent way to build our physical strength , but how effective it is when compared to hatha yoga? Can we gain as much strength doing hatha yoga , as we get from doing a gym? Also can anybody refer to some text books which will give all the asanas and the proper way to practice them , thank you.

Comment: If you are doing it in the context of physical exercise, then it is equivalent to calisthenics. Calisthenics are good for building moderate muscle and gaining weight. Hatha Yoga is something serious that needs to be done under the supervision of a guru, otherwise, the trouble can impair someone's life.

Comment: The purpose of Haṭhayoga is *not* exercise. Please don't treat it, in that manner.

Comment: @Bingming so it good for an individual to try at home ?

Comment: that depends on what you are trying. Simple āsanas such as sukhāsana, padmāsana, etc. can usually be done by anyone, but specific techniques, etc. which are advanced in nature such as trāṭaka, etc. should be done under the guidance of a proper ācārya/guru. @SoumyadipDas
Basically proper Haṭha yoga requires a guru/ācārya to guide you, just like the first comment on your post here, says.

Comment: @Bingming is trataka also not advisable for being practiced alone? It’s seems a useful technique for concentration .

Answer (score 0):

[Hatha Yoga Pradipika](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/hatha-yoga-pradipika-englis)  and [Dattatreya Yoga Samhita](https://archive.org/details/DattatreyaYogaSamhita_201808)  is a good source to learn about hatha yoga

[image]

Mudras and certain kundalini-related ideas are included in Haṭha yoga

From Hatha Yoga Pradipika

> सुराज्ये धार्मिके देशे सुभिक्ष्हे निरुपद्रवे | धनुः परमाण-पर्यन्तं
> शिलाग्नि-जल-वर्जिते | एकान्ते मठिका-मध्ये सथातव्यं हठ-योगिना || १२ ||
>
> The Yogī should practise Haṭha Yoga in a small room, situated in a
> solitary place, being 4 cubits square, and free from stones, fire,
> water, disturbances of all kinds, and in a country where justice is
> properly administered, where good people live, and food can be
> obtained easily and plentifully.
>
> एवं विधे मठे सथित्वा सर्व-छिन्ता-विवर्जितः | गुरूपदिष्ह्ट-मार्गेण
> योगमेव समभ्यसेत || १४ ||
>
> Having seated in such a room and free from all anxieties, he should
> practise Yoga, as instructed by his guru.
>
> Caution अत्याहारः परयासश्छ परजल्पो नियमाग्रहः | जन-सङ्गश्छ लौल्यं छ
> षहड्भिर्योगो विनश्यति || १५
>
> Yoga is destroyed by the following six causes:—Over-eating, exertion,
> talkativeness, adhering to rules, i.e., cold bath in the morning,
> eating at night, or eating fruits only, company of men, and
> unsteadiness
>
> अथ आसनम हठस्य परथमाङ्गत्वादासनं पूर्वमुछ्यते | कुर्यात्तदासनं
> सथैर्यमारोग्यं छाङ्ग-लाघवम || १९ ||
>
> Being the first accessory of Haṭha Yoga, ***āsana is described first.
> It should be practised for gaining steady posture, health and
> lightness of body.***

Comment: Why adhering to rules is forbidden ?thank you .

Comment: @SoumyadipDas sorry wrong translation I copied https://drsomveeryoga.com/hatha-pradipika-ch-1-15-16/ if you know hindi this can help. Wisdom lib translation is not good. Next time I will answer from internet archive. Thanks for informing

Comment: It’s alright @hope, I get it. Thank you.